# Pandas timestamp ceil resampling

Tags: pandas, resampling

I need to resample a timestamp field, but I'm not getting success with pandas' `resample` method. The table below presents resampling using two approaches: `resample` and `groupby with ceil`. Is there a way to get the result computed by the second approach using just `resample`? By the way, the result of the second approach is suitable for my project.

I already tried to use combinations of `closed` and `convetion` arguments in the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), but without success.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

periods = 12
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.date_range('2020-01-01 00:45:00', freq='15T', periods=periods),
    'value': np.random.randint(1, 10, periods),
})
df['datetime_ceil'] = df['datetime'].dt.ceil('H')
display(df)

df_agg_resample = df[['datetime', 'value']].resample('H', on='datetime').sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'datetime': 'datetime_resample'}).shift(-1)
df_agg_ceil = df[['datetime_ceil', 'value']].groupby('datetime_ceil').sum().reset_index()
df_agg = pd.concat([df_agg_resample, df_agg_ceil], axis=1)
df_agg
```

```bash
datetime    value   datetime_ceil
0   2020-01-01 00:45:00 2   2020-01-01 01:00:00
1   2020-01-01 01:00:00 3   2020-01-01 01:00:00
2   2020-01-01 01:15:00 1   2020-01-01 02:00:00
3   2020-01-01 01:30:00 5   2020-01-01 02:00:00
4   2020-01-01 01:45:00 2   2020-01-01 02:00:00
5   2020-01-01 02:00:00 7   2020-01-01 02:00:00
6   2020-01-01 02:15:00 7   2020-01-01 03:00:00
7   2020-01-01 02:30:00 6   2020-01-01 03:00:00
8   2020-01-01 02:45:00 4   2020-01-01 03:00:00
9   2020-01-01 03:00:00 1   2020-01-01 03:00:00
10  2020-01-01 03:15:00 2   2020-01-01 04:00:00
11  2020-01-01 03:30:00 3   2020-01-01 04:00:00


datetime_resample   value   datetime_ceil   value
0   2020-01-01 01:00:00 11.0    2020-01-01 01:00:00 5
1   2020-01-01 02:00:00 24.0    2020-01-01 02:00:00 15
2   2020-01-01 03:00:00 6.0 2020-01-01 03:00:00 18
3   NaT NaN 2020-01-01 04:00:00 5
```

Comment: per document, `convention` is for time index only. You can try: `df.set_index('datetime')['value'].resample('H', convention='e').sum()`.

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang , thanks for your answer, but it didn't work as `gropby with ceil` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve the same result as the second approach using the `resample` method. You can use the `origin` parameter to specify the starting point for the resampling. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd 

import numpy as np 

periods = 12
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.date_range('2020-01-01 00:45:00', freq='15T', periods=periods),
    'value': np.random.randint(1, 10, periods),
})


df['datetime_ceil'] = df['datetime'].dt.ceil('H')
display(df)

df_agg_resample = df[['datetime', 'value']].resample('H', on='datetime', origin='start').sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'datetime': 'datetime_resample'})

df_agg_ceil = df[['datetime_ceil','value']].groupby('datetime_ceil').sum().reset_index()

df_agg = pd.concat([df_agg_resample, df_agg_ceil], axis=1)

df_agg
```

Comment: Hi @AH, thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. follow the result (sorry for the presentation, but I can't format the markdown here in the comment)

datetime_resample value datetime_ceil value

0 2020-01-01 00:45:00 18.0 2020-01-01 01:00:00 11

1 2020-01-01 01:45:00 21.0 2020-01-01 02:00:00 18

2 2020-01-01 02:45:00 10.0 2020-01-01 03:00:00 18

3 NaT NaN 2020-01-01 04:00:00 2

Answer (score 0):

Let me try again.  How about this?

```
periods = 12
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': pd.date_range('2020-01-01 00:45:00', freq='15T', periods=periods),
    'value': np.random.randint(1, 10, periods),
})
df['datetime_ceil'] = df['datetime'].dt.ceil('H')
pd.concat([
    df.set_index('datetime').resample('1H')['value'].sum().reset_index().shift(-1), 
    df.set_index('datetime_ceil').resample('1H')['value'].sum().reset_index()],
    axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi @misterhuge , thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. The result is the same as that obtained using `resample`, which is not suitable for my case. By the way, the correct command would be `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', axis=0, freq='H')).agg({'value': 'sum'})`. Furthermore, I already get the expected result using `groupby with ceil`, however my question is whether it is possible to get it just using `resample` and its built-in arguments.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a better solution.  Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi @misterhuge , unfortunately it didn't work.